# Atribuir código HTML num alert Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, alert

Estou usando este alert, mas queria inserir uma quebra de texto

```
window.alert("Não existe produto cadastrado no sistema! Para continuar devemos cadastrar pelo menos um produto");
```

queria por uma quebra de linha 
 após a exclamação como faço para que ele receba valores em HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

já descobri, basta apenas colocar \n para quebra de linha

```
window.alert("Não existe produto cadastrado no sistema!\nPara continuar devemos cadastrar pelo menos um produto");
```

Comment: Não funciona no window.alert, somente \n mesmo